# Create Time Series Objects from Columns in DataFrame R

Tags: r, loops, time-series, data-manipulation

If I have a dataframe set up like this

```
 print(df3)
         date actuals actuals2 actuals3 actuals4
1  2019-01-01     193   33        39        33
2  2019-02-01     200   55        109       44
```

I'm trying something like below, but it doesn't work well

```
tots <- function(v){ 
ts(v,start=c(2019,1),end=c(2021,6),frequency=12)
}

for (i in 2:ncol(df3)){
 df_ts[i] <- tots(df3[,i])

}
```

How can I create a time series variable for each column (actuals,actuals2,actuals3,actuals4) so I have 4 separate ts() objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is going through `xts` from {zoo} and then transforming to `ts` with `as.ts()`. The argument `FUN` specifies a function to interpret the date in your data.frame.

#### edit to address comments

- You can use `window()` from stats, which is attached by default, to split the data between train and test.
- In the loop, you can use `assing()` to define the new objects grammatically.
- Personally, I would avoid working with `ts` objects (or only transform into as late as possible). For data pre-processing there are some packages that might make your life a bit easier, such as [modeltime](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modeltime/vignettes/getting-started-with-modeltime.html) and the [forecast package](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast), just to name a few.

```r
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

df3 <- tribble(
  ~date,       ~actuals, ~actuals2, ~actuals3, ~actuals4, 
  "2019-01-01",     193,        33,        39,        33, 
  "2019-02-01",     200,        55,       109,        44,
  "2019-03-01",     320,        15,        19,        22,
  "2019-04-01",     218,        25,       209,        33)

ts_tmp <- as.ts(read.zoo(df3, FUN = as.yearmon))
ts_tmp
#>          actuals actuals2 actuals3 actuals4
#> Jan 2019     193       33       39       33
#> Feb 2019     200       55      109       44
#> Mar 2019     320       15       19       22
#> Apr 2019     218       25      209       33


first_date <- df3$date %>% as.yearmon() %>% first() %>% as.numeric()
last_date <- df3$date %>% as.yearmon() %>% last() %>% as.numeric()


ts_tmp_train <- window(ts_tmp, start = first_date, end = first_date + 2/12)
ts_tmp_test <- window(ts_tmp, start = first_date + 3/12, end = last_date)
# note the division by the frequency, where each unit means a whole year


for (i in 1:ncol(ts_tmp)) {
  assign(paste0("ts_act_train", i), ts_tmp_train[, i])
  assign(paste0("ts_act_test", i), ts_tmp_test[, i])
}

ts_act_train1
#>      Jan Feb Mar
#> 2019 193 200 320
ts_act_test1
#>      Apr
#> 2019 218
```

Comment: I didn't even know that function existed! Thanks.

The problem though is what if wanted to specify a specific time frame with that function? Basically I have 2019,2020,2021 but i only want Jan2019-Dec2020 as a training set and Jan2021-June-2021 as a test set. I know you can use ts() and set that manually, but the goal is to have my code be more automated and less line by line.

Comment: Regarding the reference to xts, note that this code does not use xts at all.   It only uses zoo.  Also it needs `as.ts.zoo` from zoo.  Best to omit the `zoo::` prefixes and use `library(zoo)` before the code to ensure that the right methods are invoked.